# SQL affected row count from a batch of statements

Tags: sql-server, delphi, rowcount

I'm running the following batch of statements in a loop until the number of rows affected comes back as 0:

```
DECLARE @ScopeTable TABLE (  KeyField bigint,  PRIMARY KEY ( KeyField ) )

INSERT INTO @ScopeTable
SELECT DISTINCT DocumentID FROM [CurrentArchive].[dbo].[ItemData]
WHERE DocumentID IS NOT NULL 

INSERT INTO [CurrentArchive].[dbo].[ItemExtras] 
SELECT TOP 1024 [ItemExtras].*
FROM [ItemExtras]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [CurrentArchive].[dbo].[ItemExtras] AS TargetTable
    ON [ItemExtras].DocumentID = TargetTable.DocumentID
INNER JOIN @ScopeTable AS ScopeTable
    ON [ItemExtras].[DocumentID] = ScopeTable.KeyField
WHERE (TargetTable.DocumentID IS NULL)
```

It has worked correctly for years on many different databases, but suddenly on one particular database, it's returning 38563, which is obviously the number of rows in the "INSERT INTO @ScopeTable" part, since the other insert does a "TOP 1024".

Is there some SQL Server setting that could make it change behavior like this?  Is it improper to depend on getting a 0 back?

EDIT:  As requested, here's the (Delphi) code that runs the loop.  DataAccess.NewCommand uses an TADOCommand, and if it gets an exception, returns -1:

```
TopClause := '';
TopCount := 2048;
Finished := false;
while not Finished do
begin
   AffectedRecords := fDataAccess.NewCommand(Format(
      '%s INSERT INTO %s SELECT%s%s [%s].* FROM [%s] %s',
      [PreClause, QualifiedTable, ManyToOneClause, TopClause, Table, Table, WhereClause]));

   if AffectedRecords >= 0 then
   begin
      if TopClause = '' then // first time through
         Finished := true
      else if AffectedRecords < TopCount then // other times through
         Finished := true;
   end
   else
   begin
      // if that fails, try top 1024, 512, etc until we reach 0 or it succeeds
      TopCount := TopCount div 2;
      if TopCount = 0 then
      begin
         fTracker.LastError := 'Failed to insert items for table ' + QualifiedTable;
         raise Exception.Create(fTracker.LastError);
      end;
      TopClause := ' TOP ' + IntToStr(TopCount);
   end;
end;
```

Comment: Is it possible to add the rest of the loop code?  All of this looks good to me, but the problem might be somewhere else...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try setting NOCOUNT on before the first INSERT, then resetting it back afterwards:

```
DECLARE @ScopeTable TABLE (  KeyField bigint,  PRIMARY KEY ( KeyField ) )

SET NOCOUNT ON

INSERT INTO @ScopeTable
SELECT DISTINCT DocumentID FROM [CurrentArchive].[dbo].[ItemData]
WHERE DocumentID IS NOT NULL 

SET NOCOUNT OFF

INSERT INTO [CurrentArchive].[dbo].[ItemExtras] 
SELECT TOP 1024 [ItemExtras].*
FROM [ItemExtras]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [CurrentArchive].[dbo].[ItemExtras] AS TargetTable
    ON [ItemExtras].DocumentID = TargetTable.DocumentID
INNER JOIN @ScopeTable AS ScopeTable
    ON [ItemExtras].[DocumentID] = ScopeTable.KeyField
WHERE (TargetTable.DocumentID IS NULL)
```